# How do I get Supabase data cached in NextJs to update properly?

Tags: caching, next.js, supabase

I am using Supabase with NextJs (app router) to create a web app. Most of the data that we are using is highly dynamic, so from what I can understand, there is no static rendering.

We have structured our individual routes to have two 'pieces.' One parent component (SSC) that fetches our data, and a child component that will display/interact/update it. This works quite well in most places.

We are running into problems with one particular route. I suspect it has something to do with the way that NextJs is caching and updating cached data, but I am struggling to understand exactly what is going on under the hood. (I can't figure out how to get my debug config to work, but that is another question)

Now... This is where I get lost. Calling the updater function from the modal will instantly update the 'trips' prop in the page route. I do not understand why it does not also instantly update the 'users' prop as well? After 30 seconds or so the UI for the ScheduleSheet updates properly. The modal updates almost instantly.

Can anyone see any glaring errors?

Also could someone please explain if I am not using the caching correctly?

To put the architecture as simply as possible, here is what I have built

**1. Parent server component**
This component houses only data fetching functions using supabase.

```
export const dynamic = 'force-dynamic';

const page = async () => {
  const users = await getUsersWithTripsAndRoles();
  const trips = await getTripsWithUsersAndRoles();
  const tripTypes = await getActiveTripTypesWithTrips();
  const profile = await getCurrentUser();
  const roles = await getRoles();

  if (!users) throw new Error('Error fetching users');
  if (!trips) throw new Error('Error fetching trips');
  if (!tripTypes) throw new Error('Error fetching users');
  if (!roles) throw new Error('Error fetching roles');
  if (!profile) throw new Error('Error fetching session');

  return (
    <ScheduleSheet
      users={users}
      trips={trips}
      tripTypes={tripTypes}
      profile={profile}
      roles={roles}
    />
  );
};
```

**2. Child component handlers**
The 'ScheduleSheet' component is extremely complex. (And poorly built I might add). For that reason I have chosen not to include the code. Instead, I will include the data mutation handlers that *should* be mutating the cache, but for some reason are not. They are however correctly mutating the database.

```
const updateFn = async (
    person: NonNullable<
      Getters<typeof getTripsWithUsersAndRoles>
    >[0]['trip_to_user_to_role'][0]['user'],
    connect: boolean
  ) => {
    if (!person) throw new Error('update person not defined')

    if (allowedToEditTrips(profile)) {
      if (connect) addEmployeeToTrip(person.id, trip.id)
      if (!connect) removeEmployeeFromTrip(person.id, trip.id)

      router.refresh()
    }
  }
```

Note: this function exists in one of the many children of the ScheduleSheet. A modal, more specifically. It does exist on the same 'url' as ScheduleSheet. When it is called, the modal props update instantly, and correctly. The modal correctly displays the added employee, which is accessed through the trips prop (see step 1)

```
export async function addEmployeeToTrip(employeeId: string, tripId: string) {
    const supabase = createClientSupabaseClient()
    try {
        const companyId = await getCompanyId()

        const { error: insertError } = await supabase
            .from('trip_to_user_to_role')
            .insert({ user_id: employeeId, trip_id: tripId, company_id: companyId })


        if (insertError) throw insertError

        return {
            success: true,
            error: null as PostgrestError | null
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error:', error);
        return {
            success: false,
            error: error as PostgrestError | null
        }
    }
}
```

Note: here is the "update" function

```
export const createClientSupabaseClient = cache(() =>
    createClientComponentClient<Database>()
);
```

Note: This is used by the 'updater' function. I have no clear idea what the cache() portion of this is supposed to be doing. Reasonably sure that it should only exist on the server version of this code, but not enough to change it.